# Ubuntu On VirtualBox(No Wireless Icon)

Tags: ubuntu-15.10

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on virtualbox software, and am trying to connect to the internet witch i can't, it doesn't even show a wireless icons. My original sys is Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't see a wireless icon. You would normally configure a virtual network, so Ubuntu should see a virtual Ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You won't see a wireless icon, and that's normal.

As far as the Ubuntu installed in your VirtualBox is concerned, it has an Ethernet connection, even if the connection on your physical computer is wireless.

Now, if you don't see *any* icon at all, it's possible that your virtual network is disabled or turned off. Double check your VM settings and make sure that there's a virtual network adapter installed and connected, and that it's not set to "Host only network" if you wish it to have internet access.

More information is available in the [VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes)